# Conditional Regex If Number is +1 or equal to a specific number behind in string

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression:

```
 /^ETW([0-9C])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([A-L])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])/g
```

Which matches the following things:

1. Character 1 is always the alpha character – E
2. Character 2 is always the alpha character – T
3. Character 3 is always the alpha character – W
4. Character 4 may only be any numeric digit 0 – 9 or the alpha character C (No other alpha characters are allowed)
5. Character 5 may only be any numeric digit 0 – 9 (No alpha characters)
6. Character 6 may only be any numeric digit 0 – 9 (No alpha characters)
7. Character 7 may only be any numeric digit 0 – 9 (No alpha characters)
8. Character 8 may only be any numeric digit 0 – 9 (No alpha characters)
9. Character 9 is always one of the following alpha characters –A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L (No other alpha characters are allowed)
10. Character 10 may only be any numeric digit 0 – 9 (No alpha characters)
11. Character 11 may only be any numeric digit 0 – 9 (No alpha characters)
12. Character 12 may only be any numeric digit 0 – 9 (No alpha characters)

All these conditions are fulfilling with my RegEx but problem is now another condition is added that the `Character 12` can only be `Equal to` `Character 10` or `+1 only` from `Character 10`

How can i achieve this ?? i have tried Conditional RegEx but its not working can anyone help me out with this ??
Do i have to handle it with pragmatically i am sorry i am really new to RegEx conditional handling any helping material will also be useful.

Comment: Regular expressions might replace programming languages one day.

Comment: Regex cannot handle calculations such as "previous capture group plus 1". However, you could use two regexes in a row, one with "previous capture group" and the second with "prev capture group + 1"

Comment: @aliteralmind Hmmm so it means i have to do it pragmatically. Its not possible in RegEx.

Comment: also, i'm not sure what language you are using, so *maybe* it has special syntax for character classes that are specific to the language, but more than likely your character 4 and character 9 are wrong. Putting commas and spaces in your char classes like that should cause the char class to also match for those. IOW you should just have `[0-9C]` and `[A-L]`

Comment: @CrayonViolent Ohhh Sorry i missed that point thanks mate for the correction. I updated my Question

Comment: What flavour regex? Or more to the point, the language - PHP, JavaScript, Java, Perl ... ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Language is `PHP`

Comment: you can use `preg_replace_callback` and use the callback function to do the evaluation. If you looking to solely match, you will need to evaluate and then pop a global array with your matches, since the purpose of `preg_replace_callback` is to return an altered string, not matches.

Comment: also.. you said this is `php`, well `php` doesn't have a `g` modifier. You're probably confusing it with `javascript` to global/match-all matching. The equivalent of `g` modifier in php is to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`. If you're replacing, then `preg_replace` and `preg_replace_callback` are match and replace all by default (and you pass an additional arg to them to limit it).  I think overall, it would be more helpful if you gave more details about what you are ultimately wanting to do with this, since your solution is outside of the regex

Comment: @PHPSeeker If character 10 is `9`, what should character 12 be ? `0` ?

Comment: @devnull [**Here you go**](http://regex101.com/r/kM3iJ1) :D

Comment: @PHPSeeker ^ but seriously. You don't want to do this with (conditional) regex. I made it for fun.

Comment: Ah forgot the equality case. [New demo](http://regex101.com/r/pB0mC6). To my surprise, I've encountered a weird issue. Why is there group `17` and `18` instead of `7` and `8` ? Is it a bug ? Maybe someone could shed some light on this "issue". **Found the "issue":** The named groups are also counted as numbered groups.

Comment: @HamZa it should be Equal only if the 10th is 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to split it into two separate match operations, using the result from the first one to create the second.

```
function isValidFormat($str)
{
    $pt1 = substr($str,0,10);
    $r1 = '#^ETW(\d|C)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)([A-L])(\d)#';
    //If you're not going to use all the match groups, use
    //$r1 = '#^ETW(\d|C)\d{4}[A-L](\d)#';
    //And instead of $matches[7], use $matches[2]
    if(preg_match($r1,$pt1,$matches)>0)
    {
        $pt2 = substr($str,10);
        $pt10 = intval($matches[7]);
        $pt12M = $pt10==9 ? '9' : '('.$pt10.'|'.($pt10+1).')$';
        $r2 = '#\d'.$pt12M.'$#';
        return preg_match($r2,$pt2)>0;
    }
    else return false;
}
$isValid = isValidFormat('ETW09876D929');
var_dump($isValid);
```

You visit [this link](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hyw-1ir) and hit run/F9 to test

Comment: Thanks mate for the answer i just commented again for that case

Comment: @PHPSeeker Yep, spotted that. Updated answer and test link. Haven't commented it all, but any queries about what it's doing, let me know.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks alot it works like a charm. Plus thanks to Hamza too for helping out and mentioning the missing case. And Thanks to  Crayon Violent as well for mentioning the method of PHP.